# Autolayout still shows error after I have set margins

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am new to Swift and have recently begun learning AutoLayout. It seems pretty intuitive, but I am designing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oApN.png) something right now and am unsure of why exactly there are errors showing up. You can see more in the pictures below, but essentially, I am pinning my scrollview to the sides and to the upper and bottom edges. What other information do I need to provide?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jssmK.png)

Comment: Show us your view hierarchy in document outline.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have To add ContentView(UIView) First to ScrollView.Than add your other Component in that ContentView.

1. Drag ScrollView to UIViewController.Apply top,bottom.leading,trailing == 0
2. Add UIview(ContentView) to your ScrollView.Apply top,bottom,leading,trailing == ScrollView(top,bottom,leading,trailing)
3. **More important :-Apply equal Width & equal hight of ContentView to
   ScrollView ParentView**

for more details: -https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7